# Remote or Local Data for JQuery Autocomplete of <200 Items Using Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My Rails 3.2 application has a search bar in its navigation menu (i.e. on every page) that lets users search for product categories. Currently there are ~20 categories, but this is expected to grow to ~200 categories or so. The list of current categories can change up to once or twice a day.

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete to provide suggestions for matching product category names as users type.

Autocomplete has two options for providing the terms it suggests: local or remote. You can either provide it an array of strings and it will search on the client side, or you can provide it a URL, which it will expect to return JSON with suggested terms based on what the user is typing in real time (i.e. search is on the server).

Currently, I am using the local data approach, but I am generating this local data dynamically. In category.js.coffee:

```
$('#search').autocomplete
    source: $('#search').data('autocomplete-source')
```

I am generating the array of potential results by using a helper method, and storing the array within the search text field using an HTML5 data element:

`<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :data => { :autocomplete_source => category_array.to_json } %>`

The helper method just gathers all the Category names from the database, and puts them into an array:

```
def category_array
  Category.pluck(:name)
end
```

My question is: **is this a reasonable way to do this?**

My concern is that since the navigation bar appears on every page, I am hitting the database to gather all Category names on every single page request. I am too new to this to know if this performance concern is addressed by Rails/Postgres caching. However, adding a remote search capability for only 200 items seems a bit silly, so I assume using the local data like this will make the autocomplete feature feel faster.

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I go with the remote data approach?

Comment: I would use remote data if there can be 200+ categories (or even 50+) because i doubt many of your users will actually need more than 10 of those categories within a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems worthy of the remote option to me. You can always calculate the overhead.

**[Data Size of in KB 200+ categories] * [Number of average page requests per day]**

*vs*

**[Data Size in KB of 200+ categories] * [Number of average searches per day]**

Beyond that you can also design your remote search any way you like. For example if it would appear faster to load all the options on the first search and thereafter filter the original list on the client, build that into the source callback:

```
source: function( request, response ) { 
    // make request for all categories and send back a response
    // set a flag to indicate the data has been loaded
    // for subsequent requests and filter on `request.term`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give this a shot. The data loaded flag is an interesting idea.

Comment: Have a look at the source of [this example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) from the jquery website that has an example of caching the request client side.